# Set attribute from 2 sources in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I set my "slug" value in laravel so:

```
public function setTitleAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['title'] = $value;
        $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($value);
    }
```

This method works, but much elements at the moment has the same name and same generated slug, so I want to add additional content to slug, how can I do it? Can I do something like

```
public function setTitlePackAttribute($value, $key)
{
    $this->attributes['title'] = $value;
    $this->attributes['pack'] = $key;
    $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($value . $key);
}
```

I want to generate slug from more sources...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first mutator, `$this->attributes['title'] = $value;` is unnecessary if you don't do something about `$value`.

You can access current attributes of model via `$this->title` so you can just do something like this:

```
public function setSlugAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['slug'] = str_slug($this->title . $this->pack)
}
```

Comment: I think this does not work if the attributes `title` and `pack` are set later than `slug`.